Use the correct password to connect to PolarDB but get a password error
I encountered a strange issue while trying to connect to a PolarDB database. Following the official PolarDB manual, I deployed the database and used the default user postgres to create a new user polar, setting the password to P123. However, when I attempt to connect to the database as user polar, I receive the error message: "FATAL: password authentication failed for user 'polar'". I have confirmed that the password is correct and have set the password encryption method to md5. Below are the details of my database version and configuration:
PolarDB: v15
IP: 172.17.0.2
PORT: 5432

I have configured multiple authentication methods in pg_hba.conf, including scram-sha-256 and md5, but the issue persists. I suspect that the problem might be related to the pg_hba.conf configuration or the password encryption setting. I would appreciate any expert guidance to help resolve this connection issue.
Steps to Reproduce:

Follow the official PolarDB deployment guide: PolarDB Deployment Guide

Use the default user postgres to connect to the PolarDB database and execute the following commands to create a new user:


postgres=# set password_encryption ='md5';  
SET  
postgres=# create role polar encrypted password 'P123' login superuser;  
CREATE ROLE  


Attempt to connect to the database using the user polar:

postgres@67fd9cf2d4eb:~/primary$ export PGPASSWORD=P123   
postgres@67fd9cf2d4eb:~/primary$ psql -h 172.17.0.2 -p 5432 -U polar postgres  


Observe the error message:

psql: error: connection to server at "172.17.0.2", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "polar"  


Check the pg_hba.conf file to confirm the configuration as follows:

$ grep "^[a-z]" pg_hba.conf    
local   all             all                                     trust  
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust  
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust  
local   replication     all                                     trust  
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust  
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust  
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 scram-sha-256     
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5      
host  replication postgres  172.17.0.0/16 trust      

I hope to receive some suggestions on how to resolve this issue.
